# Not Null constraint failed in Room database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have retrieved data from the server and that data i am trying to insert into local storage of room various few of the fields are blank for which i am not able to append .

Following is my data class below

```
const val CURRENT_USER_ID = 0

@Entity
data class UserModel(val first_name: String,
                      val last_name: String,
                      val personal_image: String,
                      val status:String,
                      val message:String,
                      val token:String,
                      val user_type:String,
                      val user_id:Int,
                      val name:String,
                      val phone:String,
                      val email:String,
                      val photo:String,
                      val designation:String,
                      val interests:String,
                      val company_name:String,
                      val description:String,
                      val service_type:String,
                      val grade:String,
                      val origin:String,
                      val ownership:String,
                      val certifications:String,
                      val no_of_employees:String,
                      val production:String,
                      val address:String,
                      val city:String,
                      val state:String,
                      val country:String,
                      val zip:String,
                      val website:String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
     var UId:Int=
        CURRENT_USER_ID

}
```

Please let me know how can i get resolve this error . If any of the fields is null i want to enter empty string

Comment: `@ColumnInfo(name = "first_name", defaultValue = "")` for your columns to have defaultvalues

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to solve this:

### 1.using @ignore annotation

You can use @ignore annotation to show Room which fields might be null.

```
 public ImageData(int id, String name, String title, String description, int locationId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

    @Ignore
    public ImageData(int id, String name, String title, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
```

Additional help in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088702/12785756

### 2.using default value

Much easier way!
Just use a default value like this:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "user_name", defaultValue = "temp") val name: String
```

Answer (score 0):

> If any of the fields is null i want to enter empty string

you can assign default values to your variables by using:

```
val last_name: String = "",
```

this will take the default value of an empty string, should any of the responses be null.

Alternatively, you could just mark some of your fields as nullable:

```
val last_name: String?
```

which would then store these as null if they don't get any values

Comment: i am getting this error -> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: UserModel.first_name (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)

Comment: you have to add `val first_name: String = ""` , specifically the `= ""` to all variables